# Directly calculate electric potential due to a spherical volume charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Q:

Say we have a uniformly charged sphere with radius $R$, total charge $Q$. Now we need to find out the electric potential inside the sphere, at a distance r from the centre. I understand that we can do this by using

$$\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla}V. \tag{1}$$

But is there a way to do this by using:

$$V(r)=\int {\frac{\rho(r)}{r}d{\tau}} \tag{2}$$

to directly calculate the potential and then get the electric field from integration?

I have no idea how to do this, could someone please give me a hint on how to get started?

Comment: I am sorry, previously I misunderstood your formula. Now, using the spherical symmetry it is clear that both field and potential depend only on the distance $r$ from the center. But, how do you prove your formula? The relation we have is between charge and field, Gauss' integral theorem. What about using it, finding $\vec E(r)$ and then by integration from the center to the point $r$, proving whether your formula is correct or not?

Comment: Pay attention that if $d\tau$ is your element of volume, it also contains a factor $r^2$,s.t. I suggest you to prove your formula as I said.

Comment: His formula is correct up to a constant, but with sloppy notation. There are three $r$ symbols in the equation but they all actually represent different quantities.

Comment: I presume you meant to say "and then get the electric field by differentiation " not "integration"...?

Comment: @Sofia Um...that is not my formula...it's from my textbook

Comment: Sorry...In my second formula I forgot the constant $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$

Comment: @RuihongYuan   couldn't you tell us that the formula was proved in your book?

Answer (score 2):

Generically the potential is given by the integral,

$$ \Phi(x) = \int \rho(x') \frac{1}{\vert x - x' \vert} d\tau' ,$$

which is based on Coulomb's law of Electrostatics.

It is possible to use the spherical symmetry of $\rho$ to show that $\Phi(\Omega x ) = \Phi(x) $ for any proper rotation $\Omega$. This means we can set $x$ to be on the $z$-axis without loss of generality.

Now we write the integral in more detail ultimately using spherical coordinates for the integration.

$$ \Phi(x) =  \int \rho(x') \frac{1}{\sqrt{ x^2 + x'^2 - 2 x \cdot x'}} d\tau',$$

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \rho(r) \frac{r^2 \sin(\theta) dr d\theta d\phi }{\sqrt{ z^2 + r^2 - 2 zr\cos(\theta)}}  .$$

The integrand is independent of $\phi$ so we can perform that integration automatically getting a factor of $2\pi$ out front. We can then handle the term in the square root by performing a change of integration variable for $\theta$. Let $y=z^2+r^2-2zr \cos(\theta)$ then $dy =2zr \sin(\theta) d\theta$.

$$ \Phi(x) = 2\pi \int_0^\pi \int_0^R \rho(r) \frac{r^2 \sin(\theta) dr d\theta  }{\sqrt{ z^2 + r^2 - 2 zr\cos(\theta)}} $$

$$ = 2\pi  \int_0^R \left[ \int_0^\pi \rho(r) \frac{r^2 \sin(\theta)  d\theta  }{\sqrt{ z^2 + r^2 - 2 zr\cos(\theta)}} \right]dr $$

$$ = 2\pi  \int_0^R \left[ \int_{(z-r)^2}^{(z+r)^2} \rho(r) \frac{r^2 \frac{1}{2zr} dy }{\sqrt{y}} \right]dr $$

$$ = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \int_0^R \rho(r) r \left[   \sqrt{y} \right]_{(z-r)^2}^{(z+r)^2} dr $$

$$ = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \int_0^R \rho(r) r \left[   (z+r) - \left| z-r \right| \right]dr $$

If we are outside the charge distribution then we can write,

$$ \Phi = \frac{4\pi}{z}  \int_0^R \rho(r) r^2  dr $$

In the case of a uniform charge distribution we would get,

$$ \Phi = \frac{4\pi R^3 \rho }{3z} = \frac{q}{z} \Rightarrow \boxed{ \Phi(x) = \frac{q}{\vert x \vert} }$$

---

There are some concerns in the comments that I didn't calculate the potential inside the sphere. I wanted to leave this step up to the OP, but since he has other ways of computing the correct answer I do not see the harm in reproducing it here.

We proceed the same as before except now $0 < z < R$ whereas we had $z>R$. We will eventually arrive at,

which will be broken into to integrations : one for $z<r$ and the other for $r<z<R$. We will then use our knowledge of whether $z$ is larger or smaller than $r$ to evaluate the abolute value $\vert z-r \vert$.

$$\Phi(z) = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \left( \int_0^z \rho(r) r \left[   (z+r) - \left| z-r \right| \right]dr + \int_z^R \rho(r) r \left[   (z+r) - \left| z-r \right| \right]dr \right), $$

$$\Phi(z) = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \left( \int_0^z \rho(r) r \left[   (z+r) - ( z-r) \right]dr + \int_z^R \rho(r) r \left[   (z+r) - ( r-z) \right]dr \right), $$

$$ \Phi(z) = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \left( \int_0^z \rho(r) 2r^2dr + \int_z^R \rho(r) 2rz dr \right), $$

$$ \Phi(z) = \frac{2\pi}{z}  \left( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^z \rho(r) 4\pi r^2dr + \int_z^R \rho(r) 2rz dr \right), $$

The left hand integral is just the enclosed charge less than $z$. So we can rewrite this as,

$$ \Phi(z) = \frac{Q_{enc}(z)}{z}   + 4\pi \int_z^R \rho(r) r dr . $$

Notice that the upper bound is irrelevant in the right hand integral because all it does is contribute and additive constant to the potential. It is only the charges located at $r \leq z$ which contribute to the actual physics. We could obtain the electric field from this expression by using the fundamental theorem of calculus to differentiate the integrals with respect to $z$.

An interesting special case of this expression is when $\rho (r) $ is constant. In that case we get,

$$ \Phi(z) = \frac{\rho 4\pi z^3/3}{z}   - 2\pi z^2 \rho + (constants) , $$

$$ \Phi(z) = - \frac{2\pi}{3} \rho z^2  + (constants) . $$

This predicts that the Electric Field within the sphere grows linearly with $z$ points away from the center if the charge distribution is positive.

Comment: I just notice you actually asked about the potential inside the sphere. The idea is the same, but we no longer have $z>r$ which changes how we handle $\vert z-r \vert$. In that case you have to break the $r$-integration into two integrals for $z>r\geq 0$ and $R \geq r>z$. If $r<z$ the $\vert z-r\vert = z-r$. If $r>z$ then $\vert z-r \vert = r-z$.

Comment: Where from did you take the 1st equality? The issue is the OP is not sure on it and asks for a confirmation if his formula (2) is correct.

Comment: @Sofia, As I read it, the question asked by OP was how to evaluate the integral to get the potential.

Comment: The question is *"Now we need to find out the electric potential inside the sphere, . . . But is there a way to do this by using: (formula (2) ) to directly calculate the potential . . .?"*

Comment: @Sofia, Indeed and I demonstrated how to use formula (2) to calculate the potential. Admittedly I did this outside the sphere, but everything is there for the OP to perform the calculation on the interior.

Comment: let's speak tomorrow, it's almost morning in my country, I have to get some hours of sleep.

Comment: @Spencer Could you explain the z in your calculation? Are you putting the point on z-axis, since the spherical shell at r is actually equipotential surface?

Comment: Yes, the spherical distribution of the charge distribution tells us that the equipotential surfaces are concentric spheres. This means I lose nothing by picking a favored axis along which to measure $\Phi$. Picking the z-axis gave me a nice expression for $\hat{z}\cdot x'$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: @Spencer   only now I learnt from the OP that the formula (2) is proved in the book. But, since you know that we have spherical symmetry, you also know that the element of volume is a spherical surface of area $4\pi\r^2$ and thickness $dr$, i.e. $d\tau = 4\pi r^2dr$.

Comment: @Sofia, I would be surprised if it wasn't in his text; the formula is a standard result in electrostatics. The way the OP wrote the formula is a little off though because its not supposed to be an $r$ in the denominator, but rather the distance from an element of charge to the field point. This means the actual integrand doesn't have  the required spherical symmetry to use $d\tau=4\pi r^2$.

Comment: @Sofia, I appreciate your keeping me honest though. Thank you for the criticisms.

Comment: @Spencer  The formulas (2) is standard in electrostatics? Then it is a shame for me that I didn't know it. I am deeply in debt that you told me.

Comment: @Spencer I am sorry, I hope not to bother you too much, but the notations you used aren't good. You say "If we are ***outside the charge distribution*** ...". No, the OP seeks the potential and the field ***inside the sphere*** not outside. So, you have $r \le x$, and you have the right to integrate over $r$ only up to $x$, not up to $R$. By Gauss' theorem and by the spherical symmetry, the field at a point $x$ is established by the charges inside a sphere of radius $x$.

Comment: @Sofia, I've changed it to include the calculation for the interior of the sphere.

Comment: @Spencer excellent!

Comment: @Sofia The formula the OP gives is a natural extension of a point charge potential $k\frac{q}{r}$. If you have a charge distribution instead of a point charge, then the voltage from each infinitesimal point is $k\frac{\rho(r)dxdydz}{r}$ and integrating over volume adds up every point. Also note if you plug in the charge density of a point charge using dirac delta functions into the OP's equation, you recover $k\frac{q}{r}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether the formula (2) in the question, is correct.

Let's calculate the field $E$ by Gauss' integral law, taking in consideration ***the spherical symmetry*** and the fact that ***the field is parallel to the normal*** of any sphericl surface concentric with the sphere of radius $R$

$$\int_0^r \frac {\rho}{\epsilon_0} (4\pi r'^2 dr') = \frac {4\pi r^2}{\epsilon_0} E(r). \tag{i}$$

Thus, one gets

$$E(r) = \frac {\rho}{\epsilon_0} \frac {r}{3}, \ \ \ \text {or,} \ \ \ E(r)= \frac {Q(r)}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}, \tag{ii}$$

where $Q(r)$ means the charge encapsulated inside the spherical volume of radius $r$. Now we can calculate $V(r)$ and see if the formula (1) in the question is correct.

$$V(r) = \int_0^r E \ dr' = \frac {\rho \ r^2}{6\epsilon_0}, \ \ \ \text {or,} \ \ \ V(r) = \frac {Q(r)}{8\pi \epsilon_0 r}. \tag{iii}$$

Now, let's calculate $V(r)$ with the formula (2) in the question, in which let's introduce the multiplicative constant $1/(12\pi\epsilon_0)$.

$$V(r) = \frac {1}{12\pi\epsilon_0}\int_0^r \frac {\rho}{r'} \ d\tau = \int_0^r \frac {\rho}{3\epsilon_0 r'} \ (r'^2 dr') = \frac {\rho r^2}{6\epsilon_0}, \ \ \ \text {or,} \ \ \ V(r) = \frac {Q(r)}{8\pi \epsilon_0 r}. \tag{iv}$$

Now by comparing with $\text {(iii)}$, the formula (2) in the question is confirmed.

About your last question, how to calculate the electrical field, you can either use formula $\text {(ii)}$, apply your formula (1) to the before-last expression in $\text {(iii)}$ or in $\text {(iv)}$. Again, due to the spherical symmetry of the problem the gradient of the potential is along the direction of the field, simply $E(r) = \frac {dV(r)}{dr}$. You can check that you get again the formulas $\text {(ii)}$.

Answer (score 0):

For a different way using Laplace's Equation look at
http://hyperphysics.phyastr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/laplace.html

Hmmmm: Not sure, but the link doesn't seem to work: alternatively search for
LaPlace's and Poisson's Equations hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu